# If statement with then clause (LISP)

Tags: if-statement, lisp

So I'm trying to teach myself lisp, I'm currently using this site as a reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/lisp_if_construct.htm

I don't quite understand why the then clause is executed, despite the fact that the if clause is false?

```
(setq a 10)
(if (> a 20)
   then (format t "~% a is less than 20"))
(format t "~% value of a is ~d " a)
```

The output is:

```
a is less than 20
value of a is 10
```

Does the then clause just always execute, even when the if statement is false? (which in this case it is).

Any help would be appreciated, also sorry if my terminology is totally incorrect I'm still new to Lisp!

Comment: That tutorial seems a bit rubbish. There are good free Lisp books available online, such as Peter Seibel's [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) an if has 3 elements. `test-expression` eg `(> a 10)`, a `then-expression` eg `(- a 10)` and an `else-expression` eg. `a`:

```
(if (> a 10) ; if a is larger than 10
    (- a 10) ; then return the value of a minus 10
    a)       ; else return the value of a
```

Look at your code:

```
(if (> a 20)                          ; if a is larger than 20
    then                              ; then return the value of "then"
    (format t "~% a is less than 20")); else print a is less than 20 to screen
```

In this example they provided the then clause as the single variable `then`. Since the test is false the else-expression is always printed.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not quite sure I understand your explanation? why does then return a value, despite the if statement not being satisfied?

Comment: `then` is not a keyword so it's assumed to be a the code to be executed when the test is true.If the test is true you would have got the error that `then` was not a bound variable. Every symbol evaluated is a variable, just like `a` in your example.

Comment: Also you can test out the lisp code directly on the site, in case you wanted to fiddle with it :) But yes I am quite confused seeing as how when they use then they get a different outcome compared to when they omit it.

Comment: It looks like its using CLISP so its Common Lisp. I understand the confusion. The example just has `then` as the expression to be evaluated in the event the test is true and it won't be evaluated so that s why you see text. I'll updated my answer.

Comment: No.. `(> a 20)` is the test. If it's true, then the expression `then` is executed. If it's not true, then teh expression  `(format t "~% a is less than 20")` is executed, `then` is not a keyword but the action if eg. `a` were to be `21`. It would fail because `then` still is an unbound variable but since it isn't executed in the example since the test is false it could be anything.

Comment: but then is executed in the example given? the test is false in the example given, so why does then execute?

Comment: Here is a better example `(if (< 2 1) 3 5)`. This becomes `5` since the test is false, just like in your example. if you switch it to `(if (> 2 1) 3 5)` the result is `3`. If you do the same in your example then the expression `then` will be evaluated. Thus your example has a false test and does not evaluate its then expression `then` but its else expression `(format t "~% a is less than 20")`. `then` in the code is an expression to be evaluated if the test is true, not a keyword!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145498/discussion-between-joe-dirt-and-sylwester).